# Editing List of list of list in Python

Tags: python, list, element, nested-lists

I am trying to edit elements in my list of list of list but it is editing multiple elements.

```
    L1 = [[0,0] for count in range(2)]
    L2 = [L1 for count in range(2)]
    L2[0][0][0] = 5
    print(L2)
```

What I expect is [[[5, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]

But what I get is [[[5, 0], [0, 0]], [[5, 0], [0, 0]]]

It seems that I am editing the original list. Can someone explain how to edit a single element or set up nested lists where this effect won't occur.

Many thanks

Comment: Every element of L2 is the same list as L1: `all(a is L1 for a in L2)` is True.

Comment: Your `L2` is holding multiple references to `L1`

Comment: in L2, it's a reference to lists made in L1. Python lists are mutable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reuse the variable:

```
L2 = [[[0,0] for count in range(2)] for count in range(2)]
```

Then the inner part `[[0,0] for count in range(2)]` will get recreated every time as a fresh, separate list.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri The linked questions are generally about a list that has been multiplied, e.g. `[[0] * 2] * 2`. OP's case is ever so slightly different.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri like that?